# Shortcut to comment out multiple lines with Python Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

What is the shortcut to comment out multiple lines with Python Tools for Visual Studio?

Comment: for me, you answered my question, install Python Tools for Visual Studio  VS was highlighting first class symbols but that's about it, strangely only barks when using the normal hotkeys, without the tools, maybe this is the intention because it works for things like JSON and XML...  thanks for the slight manipulation MS

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> adds the `#` in VS for selected lines.

<kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL+U</kbd> removes the `#` in VS for selected lines.

Comment: It is done with the Edit > Advanced > Comment Selection command. By opening the Edit > Advanced menu you can see that shortcut is.

Comment: Hey @manojlds could you also include removing multi-line comments please? would be really helpful.

Comment: is there a way  to remap ``ctrl+k`` + ``ctrl+c`` to ``ctrl + shift + /``?

Comment: it works for me

Answer (score 5):

To make the comment of a block, it is a sequence of keys: <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and to un-comment <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>.

Here are some other very useful keys for Python:

[image: Short Keys for Visual Studio 2015 - Python]

Comment: In MacOS, change Ctrl to Cmd

Answer (score 2):

On python the only way is `""" ... """`, practically just a string.

Comment: You misunderstand the question. Most Python editors provide a simple mechanism for adding # to multiple lines at once. I'm asking if Python Tools for Visual Studio provides such a mechanism.

Comment: Also, this is not a comment. If it comes right after the beginning of a module/class/function it is a docstring, but not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign the shortcut key of the:
`Edit.CommentSelection` and `Edit.UncommentSelection` functions.

This is done by:

- Open Options (Menu: **Tools** > **Options...**)
- Choose **Environment** > **Keyboard**
- In the **Show commands containing** type: `Edit.CommentSelection` and/or `Edit.UncommentSelection`
- Now choose the shortcut key you want and press **Assign**.

[image: Edit Comment Shortcut keys]

Note: `Edit.ToggleLineComment` and `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` are not working when editing Python in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to comment out any line in Python (when using Visual Code) then the shortcut is:

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>  (Ctrl button plus forward
slash)

Comment: The question asks about Visual Studio and is tagged accordingly. The question and the tag are quite clear that this is not about visual code. Why do you answer with a solution for visual code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to highlight *all* the previous written code that you wish to comment out, then press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**K**</kbd> and then <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**C**</kbd>.

You will not experience any bugs or altered code during the process.

Comment: Keep in mind this process is the most efficient way with some high-light delay, depending on the system.

Comment: Which is true for all hot key approaches, which in turn the question asks specifically about. This does not put your answer apart from existing ones. Nevertheless, if you wish to add info to any of your posts, doing so by [edit]ing the post is better than to explain down here in the comments, which are at risk of being deleted at some point.

Comment: @Yunnosch It states that bugs and code will not be altered using this process

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer].

Comment: Which is probably why the question specifically asks for a hot key for longer sections of code.... But fine, if you think that is the addtional insight thanks for hunoring me and explaining.

Comment: @Yunnosch That is true thanks for the recommendation, I will add more insight to my original post instead of making comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will take the tour and read how to answer, looks like I have a lot left to learn. Thanks for the links.

Comment: True, but not a problem. Everybody learns. Don't you think that a higher reputation protects me from learning new things here. ;-) Nice that you take feedback so professionally.

Comment: Yes, I noticed these things happening over time, some times the many changes prevented me from excelling in my niche, but with patience and persistence I've decided to move on from it and learn breadth first, one step at a time. I think a higher reputation is necessary and will come in time with the right ethic. 
Thanks again. I try.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is select the block of code and type <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**1**</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.